# tomcat does not uses JDBCRealm instead it sticks to UserDatabaseRealm

Tags: tomcat, forms-authentication

I have configured JDBCRealm in my tomcat server.xml under engine tag, but tomcat sticks to UserDatabaseRealm.

**server.xml**

```
  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
  <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->

  <Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
    debug="99" driverName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
    connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" 
    connectionName="topjobs" connectionPassword="full2work"
    userTable="users"
    userNameCol="user_name"
    userCredCol="user_pass"
    userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" />
```

**tomcat log:**

> FINE: Failed to authenticate user [uname1] with realm
>   [org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm]

Comment: Are launching the Tomcat from within Eclipse and made sure you are editing the correct server.xml?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `JDBCRealm` since it's single-threaded. You probably should use `DataSourceRealm` instead. Also, the `debug` attribute – which seems to occur in every question about how-to-configure Tomcat – is not a valid attribute on a `<Realm>`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting tomcat from within eclipse does not seem to read Server.xml file changes. 
I was able to get the JDBC realm changes reflected and working correctly, after deploying the war outside Eclipse and starting tomcat from commandline using start.bat.